# Odoo - Show list of users that belongs to a group

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I want to get in a field all the users that belongs to a group. I tried this but is not working

```
managers = fields.Many2many('res.users', string="Managers in group",
default=lambda self: self.env['res.users'].search([('id','in','module.group_pos_manager')]))
```

Im getting this error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
    "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 643, in
    _handle_exception
        return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 301, in
    _handle_exception
        raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause ValueError: Invalid domain term ('id', 'in', 'module.group_pos_manager')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [two cases](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/osv/expression.py#L998-L1000) when using `in` or `not in` operators, the value (right) can be a list or a boolean (The boolean case is an abuse and handled for backward compatibility)

You can use `self.env.ref` to get the list of users that belongs to a group using the group's external identifier

***Example:***

```
default=lambda self: self.env.ref('point_of_sale.group_pos_manager').users
```

***Edit:***

You can use a function to compute the domain

***Example***

```
def _get_domain(self):
    return [('id', 'in', self.env.ref('point_of_sale.group_pos_manager').users.ids)]

managers = fields.Many2many('res.users', string="Managers in group", domain=_get_domain)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Kenly. Is it a way to use this as a domain in XML?

Comment: Do you need to use a domain to show only users from the pos manager group?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. But maybe I can do the domain in python?

Comment: Yes, you can use a function to compute the domain

Comment: Thanks Kenly, I used with a lambda domain and It worked :)